# Is there any chance to change drag map direction key(Alt+Shift+Drag) to Ctrl+Drag in openlayers 5(keybinding)

Tags: openlayers, map-directions, openlayers-5, angular-openlayers

- in my app am using angular 6 and openlayers V5.
- am very new for this openlayers
- i have done directions, am able to set view direction(input client's choice)
- i have changeling to drag on map directions using Ctrl+Drag instead of Alt+Shift+Drag
- example is [Rotate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/rotation.html)

### map-component.ts

```
this.source = new OlXYZ({
   url: 'http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
});
this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
   source: this.source
});
this.view = new OlView({
   center: fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
   zoom: 3,
   enableRotation: true
  // rotation: rotation
});
this.map = new OlMap({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [this.layer],
   view: this.view
});
this.view.setRotation(Math.PI / 180 * 90);

//this code will get list of roatate interations
console.log(this.map.controls.getArray()[1].map_.interactions.array_[0].condition_.name);
console.log(this.map.interactions.array_[0].condition_.name);
```

- please check above code and how to change the defaults controls of rotate map drag rotation keys,
- please save my days
- thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.map = new OlMap({
   target: 'map',
   layers: [this.layer],
   view: this.view,
   interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({altShiftDragRotate: false}).extend([
      new ol.interaction.DragRotate({condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly})
   ])
});
```